# kABPersonEmailProperty returns weird stuff

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

I am tring to get email address of ABRecordRef like this:

```
ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
NSString *email = [(NSString*) ABRecordCopyValue( ref, kABPersonEmailProperty ) autorelease];
NSLog(@"%@", email);
```

It returning this:

```
_$!<Home>!$_ (0x6840af0) - test@test.com (0x6840cc0)
```

What's this stuff around the email? and how can I get rid of it?Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`kABPersonEmailProperty` is of type `kABMultiStringPropertyType`. There is no single email address property, a person might have an email address for work, one for home, etc.
You can get an array of all email addresses by using `ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues`:

```
ABMultiValueRef emailMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
NSArray *emailAddresses = [(NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailMultiValue) autorelease];
CFRelease(emailMultiValue);
```

To get the labels of the email addresses, use `ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex`. "`_$!<Home>!$`" is a special constant that's defined as `kABHomeLabel`, there's also `kABWorkLabel`.

Comment: and it's possible to know the tag of that email? if is from work, personal, etc??

Answer (score 1):

Basically more details for @omz answer. Here is the code I used that extracts home email and the name of the person:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); i++) {
        NSString *label = (__bridge NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emails, i);
        if ([label isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABHomeLabel]) {
            NSString *email = (__bridge NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, i);
            _emailTextField.text = email;
        }
    }
    CFRelease(emails);


    NSString *first = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSString *last = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    if (first && first.length > 0 && last && last.length > 0) {
        _nicknameTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", first, last];
    } else if (first && first.length > 0) {
        _nicknameTextField.text = first;
    } else {
        _nicknameTextField.text = last;
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: how can I implement this in `Swift` how can I loop `CFIndex`

Answer (score 0):

Try out this......

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
// Display only a person's phone, email, and birthdate
NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty],
[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty],
[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonBirthdayProperty], nil];
picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
```